# Getting the first duplicate element of a circular list

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to get the first duplicate element from a circular list. e.g.

```
[1,-2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]     => Just 3
[0,-2, 9, 2, 3, 4, -23,- 2] => Just (-2)
```

v1:

```
firstDup :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
firstDup [] = Nothing
firstDup (x:xs)
  | [x] `intersect` xs == [x]   =  Just x
  | otherwise         = firstDup xs
```

v2:

```
firstDup' :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
firstDup' = go Set.empty
  where
    go _ [] = Nothing
    go z (x:xs)
      | x `Set.member` z = Just x
      | otherwise        = go (Set.insert x z) xs
```

I expect v1 and v2 produce the same result, but they don't.

```
firstDup       . cycle       $ [1,-2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]  ==> Just 1
firstDup'      . cycle       $ [1,-2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]  ==> Just 3
```

I'd like to know why v1 and v2 work produce different results.

Comment: ``[x] `intersect` xs == [x]`` is the same as ``x `elem` xs``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the predicate

```
[x] `intersect` xs == [x]
```

is always **true**, since `cycle` repeats the list infinite time as

```
[1, -2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 1, -2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, ...]
```

and `1` must be an element of `[-2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 1, -2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, ...]`

so

```
[1] `intersect` [-2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 1, -2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, ...] = [1]
```

that is why `V1` `firstDup` return `Just 1`.

In `V2`, `firstDup'` recursively constructs a Set like:

```
{}
{1}
{1, -2}
{1, -2, 3}
{1, -2, 3, 2, ...}
```

and check the next inserted element whether is element of the Set as:

```
1  `Set.member` {}
-2 `Set.member` {1}
3  `Set.member` {1, -2}
2  `Set.member` {1, -2, 3}
3  `Set.member` {1, -2, 3, 2}
```

Note that `3` is a member of `{1, -2, 3, 2}`, so `firstDup'` return `Just 3`.

Answer (score 3):

In `v1`, it's returning the first element that has a duplicate somewhere to the **right** of itself in the list.

In `v2`, it's returning the first element that has a duplicate somewhere to the **left** of itself in the list.

In a circular list, the first element will always have a duplicate somewhere to the right, so `v1` will always return the first element. Meanwhile, `v2` waits until an element has been seen before.